# present users a login prompt? /bin/login? getty?

Tags: shell, security, login, getty

I have a service that execs a command when a user connects to it through a socket, and redirects everything it receives to the executed program.

It works ok with shells like bash, giving the user a remote shell.

Instead of forking bash or sh, I'd like to run something that asks for user and password, like `/bin/login`

Is that the correct command to run? Isn't there anything that a non-root service could use to do the same? I thinks `getty` calls `/bin/login`, but can I just run it as a user?

I guess I could install telnetd and redirect to `telnet localhost` but I'd rather not run a telnet server.

Comment: Why are you not using ssh?

Comment: I'm trying to build a shared shell that's exposed as part of another program. Like [cloud9](http://c9.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to ask for a password?

```
print $prompt
read $response
```

If you want to know how to authenticate your users, ideally you'd write your program as being pam-aware, following one of the pam developer guides all ofer the Interwebs.  One example is http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html.  You may also have a helper program on the system which you can use for this purpose, such as unix_chkpwd, which you could use after spawning a child process and switching to the target user.  But the pam application developer interface is pretty easy, so doing the auth yourself is probably well within reason.